# Extract smartwatch firmware bin file

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, binwalk

I'm trying to extract files from a bin file that's the firmware of a smartwatch.
I tried using

```
binwalk -Mre firmware.bin
```

but got no files, this is the result:

[image: binwalk result]

How should I extract/modify this bin file ?
This is the [file link to check](https://update.ute-tech.com.cn/ble/b5f657fe23dbd12aa96abe70932618c0/RH192IA/1610954814_9204.bin).

Comment: It's firmware for an ARM Cortex-M SOC, not a packaged collection of separate files.  Using `strings` will give you some information as will disassembling THUMB instructions from offset `0x00000600`.

Comment: So how can I modify the firmware ?